# raspberry pi 4 autostart rdesktop

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi4, autostart

I'm having trouble automatically starting rdesktop on my raspberry pi 4.

I'll give you how I have it configured to see if you can help me find the error and thus be able to solve it

I edit the following file with this comment

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

I add the following line

```
@lxterminal -e rdesktop -f 192.168.1.178 -u USER -p PASS
```

configuring them that way in the raspberry pi 3, they work perfectly but in the raspberry pi 4 there is no way that it work

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and found the method below :

**Create a shell file**

We first need to create a shell file -

```
sudo nano rdesktop0.sh
```

Then add your rdesktop command to the file. Save the file and close it.

Next we need to make the file executable, enter this into the console.

```
sudo chmod +x hello-world.sh
```

Now we have a functioning shell script to run the command, I'd recommend testing it by running the following command :

```
sh rdesktop0.sh
```

**Executing the file on startup**

Use nano to create/edit a file here -

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/autostart/myapp.desktop
```

Then add the following lines -

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=sh rdesktop *variables*
```

Reboot and it should work ...

Sources:

- Create a Shell script : https://www.circuitbasics.com/how-to-write-and-run-a-shell-script-on-the-raspberry-pi/
- Run a command on startup :https://www.tomshardware.com/uk/how-to/run-script-at-boot-raspberry-pi

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal write this code

sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

then ;

@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi

@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi

@xscreensaver -no-splash

@point-rpi

@lxterminal -e python /file_path.py        **for Python File

@lxterminal -e java -jar /file_path.jar     **for Java File

and CTRL+X  reboot